# How can I use str_extract to obtain specific info from this grouped variable?

Tags: r

Have tried to play around with str_extract and regex, but can't get it to work.

I have a character variable called parameter with a lot of information in it:

```
z <- ("Class26 diesel EuEuro2 LF: 55,0% ETF: 15% Ferry-Routing: Normal Ferry-Class: RoPaxMixed VehicleEmptyWeight: 11,0 BioFuelShare: 0,01 %")
```

I would like to create new variables for LF, ETF, and bio fuel share

Desired output would be this:

```
df <- data.frame (ETF  = c("15", "20", ...),
                  LF = c("55.0", "65.0", ...),
                  Bio_Fuel_Share = c("0.01", "0.02", ...) 

                  )
```

Would highly appreciate the most simple code possible, as that would make it easier for me to replicate it other places.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your desired output look like? Please provide an example.

Comment: Good point, have edited my original question!

Comment: Is your original data multiple character vectors? E.g., in your output you have `LF = 55` and `ETF = 15` together, can we expect the input to consist of multiple character vectors of similar structure?

Comment: Yes, multiple character vectors of similar structure! Although they might differ somewhat slightly, i.e.:

y <- ("Class40 diesel EuEuro6 LF: 78,0% ETF: 20% Ferry-Routing: Normal Ferry-Class: RoPaxMixed VehicleEmptyWeight: 14,0 BioFuelShare: 5,56 %")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using base R for the extraction. I've created an additional example in your character vector to check it can iterate over more than one value successfully.

```r
# Create data
z <- c(
    "Class26 diesel EuEuro2 LF: 55,0% ETF: 15% Ferry-Routing: Normal Ferry-Class: RoPaxMixed VehicleEmptyWeight: 11,0 BioFuelShare: 0,01 %",
    "Class26 diesel EuEuro2 LF: 20,0% ETF: 65% Ferry-Routing: Normal Ferry-Class: RoPaxMixed VehicleEmptyWeight: 11,0 BioFuelShare: 0,02 %"
)

# Create regex pattern to match the percentages
# : any number of numbers, zero or one comma
# any number of numbers, optional space, percent 
numeric_pattern  <- ": \\d*?,?\\d*?\\s?%"

prefixes  <- c("ETF", "LF", "BioFuelShare")
all_matches  <- sapply(prefixes, function(prefix) {
    pattern  <- paste0(prefix, numeric_pattern)
    pattern_match  <- regmatches(z, gregexpr(pattern, z))
    match_without_spaces  <- gsub("\\s+", "", pattern_match)
    number_in_match  <- gsub("^.+:|%", "", match_without_spaces)
    number_as_numeric  <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", number_in_match))
    number_as_numeric
})

data.frame(all_matches) 

#   ETF LF BioFuelShare
# 1  15 55         0.01
# 2  65 20         0.02
```

**EDIT:** I have simplified this - realised there was no need for an outer `lapply` as all these functions are already vectorised.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sam! That's beautiful. My dataset constants 3.6 million rows, so it will take a while to run. Will test it later :)

Comment: @DavidFærgeman hmmm ok - imagine that 3.6m strings might not all be written perfectly.  If there is no number at all you will just get `NA` silently but if there are typos like `55,,5%` then you'll get an `NAs introduced by coercion` warning. Will be interested to see how many warnings you get.

Comment: Hi SamR, sorry for the late reply. Actually the data quality is really high! It's more the issue that there way too many rows to run the script on the entire dataset. But it works perfectly for subsets with the specific countries and business units Im analyzing. Thanks again for your help - much appreciated!

Comment: @DavidFærgeman glad it works - feel free to accept the answer! Interesting that 3.6m rows is too many - out of interest, did it run out of memory or just take too long to run? If the former, how much RAM does the computer you are running this on have?

Comment: Too long to run - Running it all on an 8 GB Macbook M1, but uploaded the entire dataset to a SQL database, which I am pulling the data I need from.